# Bootstrap won't compile css SyntaxError: Cannot read property 'toCSS'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine

I am using Google App engine and Bootstrap 3 with an Ubuntu local environment. When I try to load a page the browser returns this error which I think is essentially saying less.js can't compile the .css file. Pre-compiled bootstrap is not used in my system as I pull in parts in our less and work from there. This error appears 10% of the time.

```
SyntaxError: Cannot read property 'toCSS' of null
in admin-bootstrap-theme.less 
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7952:30
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7860:13
at callback.type (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7809:13)
at handleResponse (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7734:13)
at doXHR (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7754:9)
at loadFile (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7803:5)
at loadStyleSheet (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7827:5)
at loadStyleSheets (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7867:9)
at Object.less.refresh (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7944:5)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7970:6
```

Similarly, this error appears along side the first.

```
SyntaxError: Cannot read property 'toCSS' of null
in admin-bootstrap.less 
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7952:30
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7860:13
at callback.type (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7809:13)
at handleResponse (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7734:13)
at doXHR (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7754:9)
at loadFile (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7803:5)
at loadStyleSheet (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7827:5)
at loadStyleSheets (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7867:9)
at Object.less.refresh (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7944:5)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/less.js:7970:6
```

Finally, the more confusing part and also common part is this error which is much more common, without much of a stacktrace.

```
NameError: .box-shadow is undefined
in theme.less on line 28, column 3:

27  @shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
28  .box-shadow(@shadow);
29
```

So I have tried reinstalling all my files with proper permissions. I recently updated python. I tried saving the files without a BOM as discussed in another post. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer when my coworker and I were double checking our dependencies. Turns out that the version of less.js was very low 1.7.3. When we upgraded the compiler to 2.5.3 the compilation succeeded and everything was a success.